# What would be a good way to code a routine to show areas of HTML with AngularJS and Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am so far using a method similar to this:

```
class StateService implements IStateService {

    display = {
        alert: null,
        content: null,
        header: null,
        init: null,
        modal: null,
        preview: null,
    }

   show = {
        modal: () => {
            this.display.content = false;
            this.display.header = false;
            this.display.modal = true;
            this.display.preview = true;
        },
        preview: () => {
            this.display.content = false;
            this.display.header = true;
            this.display.modal = false;
            this.display.preview = true;
        }
    }

}
```

I inject the stateService into my controller and on my HTML page I have DIVs that contain:

```
 ng-show="ctrl.stateService.display.content"  etc.
```

Is there a better way that I could do this. The way I have now does not seem to be a very clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way that I could do this. The way I have now does not seem to be a very clean solution.

Really depends upon what you are doing. If you want to reuse `display` in various controllers and want all this configurability then this is the way to go.

If you are annoyed by the length of `ctrl.stateService.display.content` You *could* put `display` directly on `$scope` e.g `$scope.display = this.stateService.display` and you would have:

```
ng-show="display.content"
```

But it is really up to you.